# Bitrise + Detox + React-native - Hello World Example hangs on detox.init

Tags: react-native, jestjs, detox, bitrise

I'm trying to get the [react-native "Hello World" app](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) setup with Detox and running on Bitrise.io. I went through the react-native-cli getting started guide and am trying to run the simplest detox test using Detox + Jest on Bitrise with it.

The specific error I'm encountering is the `device` and `element` globals not being defined (see log or in the link below). From what I've researched so far, this is caused by `detox.init` not ever finishing.

Is there some basic config with Bitrise that I'm missing? The `detox test` command runs locally for me just fine.

I'm using a free Bitrise account, and the project is public. You can see a failed build here: https://app.bitrise.io/build/e7926ddfc759288f#?tab=log

The repo is also public: https://github.com/jamesopti/react-native-test/blob/add_detox/AwesomeProject/e2e/firstTest.spec.js

Thanks in advance!

**Bitrise Error Log**

```sh
Example: should have welcome screen
Example: should have welcome screen [FAIL]
FAIL e2e/firstTest.spec.js (122.008s)
  Example
    ✕ should have welcome screen (8ms)
  ● Example › should have welcome screen
    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 120000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 120000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
      at mapper (../node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:25:45)
  ● Example › should have welcome screen
    ReferenceError: device is not defined
      1 | describe('Example', () => {
      2 |   beforeEach(async () => {
    > 3 |     await device.reloadReactNative();
        |           ^
      4 |   });
      5 | 
      6 |   it('should have welcome screen', async () => {
```

**bitrise.yml**

```xml
---
format_version: '8'
default_step_lib_source: https://github.com/bitrise-io/bitrise-steplib.git
project_type: react-native
trigger_map:
- push_branch: "*"
  workflow: primary
- pull_request_source_branch: "*"
  workflow: primary
workflows:
  deploy:
    description: "## ..."
    steps:
    - activate-ssh-key@4.0.3:
        run_if: '{{getenv "SSH_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY" | ne ""}}'
    - git-clone@4.0.17: {}
    - script@1.1.5:
        title: Do anything with Script step
    - yarn@0.1.0:
        inputs:
        - workdir: AwesomeProject
        - command: install
    - install-missing-android-tools@2.3.7:
        inputs:
        - gradlew_path: "$PROJECT_LOCATION/gradlew"
    - android-build@0.10.0:
        inputs:
        - project_location: "$PROJECT_LOCATION"
    - certificate-and-profile-installer@1.10.1: {}
    - xcode-archive@2.7.0:
        inputs:
        - project_path: "$BITRISE_PROJECT_PATH"
        - scheme: "$BITRISE_SCHEME"
        - export_method: "$BITRISE_EXPORT_METHOD"
        - configuration: Release
    - deploy-to-bitrise-io@1.9.2: {}
  primary:
    steps:
    - activate-ssh-key@4.0.3:
        run_if: '{{getenv "SSH_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY" | ne ""}}'
    - git-clone@4.0.17: {}
    - yarn@0.1.0:
        inputs:
        - workdir: AwesomeProject
        - command: install
        title: Yarn Install
    - yarn@0.1.0:
        inputs:
        - workdir: AwesomeProject
        - command: test
        title: Unit tests
    after_run:
    - detox
  detox:
    steps:
    - cocoapods-install@1.9.1:
        inputs:
        - source_root_path: "$BITRISE_SOURCE_DIR/AwesomeProject/ios"
    - npm@1.1.0:
        title: Install Global
        inputs:
        - workdir: "$BITRISE_SOURCE_DIR/AwesomeProject"
        - command: install -g detox-cli react-native-cli
    - script@1.1.5:
        inputs:
        - working_dir: "$BITRISE_SOURCE_DIR/AwesomeProject"
        - content: |-
            #!/usr/bin/env bash

            brew tap facebook/fb
            export CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
            brew install fbsimctl
            brew tap wix/brew
            brew install applesimutils --HEAD
        title: Install detox utils
    - script@1.1.5:
        inputs:
        - working_dir: "$BITRISE_SOURCE_DIR/AwesomeProject"
        - content: |-
            #!/usr/bin/env bash

            detox build --configuration ios.sim.debug
        title: Detox Build
    - script@1.1.5:
        inputs:
        - working_dir: "$BITRISE_SOURCE_DIR/AwesomeProject"
        - content: |-
            #!/usr/bin/env bash

            detox test --configuration ios.sim.debug --cleanup
        title: Detox Test
app:
  envs:
  - opts:
      is_expand: false
    PROJECT_LOCATION: AwesomeProject/android
  - opts:
      is_expand: false
    MODULE: app
  - opts:
      is_expand: false
    VARIANT: ''
  - opts:
      is_expand: false
    BITRISE_PROJECT_PATH: AwesomeProject/ios/AwesomeProject.xcworkspace
  - opts:
      is_expand: false
    BITRISE_SCHEME: AwesomeProject
  - opts:
      is_expand: false
    BITRISE_EXPORT_METHOD: ad-hoc
meta:
  bitrise.io:
    machine_type: elite
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a very generic bug and can be caused by multiple things (incompatible OS/jest + detox versions/node + detox versions, etc).

If you're using MacOS, an option you can take in able to check what's going wrong in Bitrise's VM is connecting via [Screen Sharing](https://devcenter.bitrise.io/en/builds/build-data-and-troubleshooting/remote-access.html#remote-access-with-screenshare): I'd suggest adding a `while someFileDoesntExist` (to stop iteration naturally without the abort button) in your current workflow after the packages installation steps (node, detox, jest etc) and then checking if its the same one you're running locally.

If that's not the case, check if the VM is running the same simulator -- phone model && OS version; if its not, then you can specify the simulator & OS version in your detox configuration.

If that also didn't work, I'm not sure what it could be :(